# Deploy node.js server application (best practice)

Tags: node.js, deployment

I wonder if my way to deploy of node.js application is good or can be improved and how, and if there are some best practices.

Consider it's a large application and can contains unhandled exeption that will make the node server crash (even using unit test, we're not sure it's 100% crash safe) I use forever for make the server always running (I could also use pm2, but the pourpose it's the same). So I build a systemd script for use this as service like "service nodeapp start|stop|status"

I think the best solution it's run node "raw" without forever or pm2, still using systemd, but I think the risk of crashes it's too high.

The server it's behind a nginx proxy, and I also added logrotate script for log maintenance.

Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of checklists both on the internet and here on stackoverflow. 
My personal checklist is:

- setting node_env to staging
- run all the unit tests
- deploy on a staging env
- run all the scripts on the server
- if tests passes change node_env on prod and deploy

If you want to skip some tests and be sure that the environament is the same on dev and prod there is a fairly new things called docker but in the first time ot will add some complexity. 
Hopefully when you have all setted down with docker it should not be too much intrusive.

Ps. Use forever, if you're using docker you could restart the container but it's not that great